# android change webview when change a tabstrip

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, webview, android-viewpager

i wonder if someone can help me get it to work, i want to change the webview url every time i change a tab in the tabstrip

i am a new developer so any kind of help will be great.

the main code of the pager and tabs

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;
import com.readystatesoftware.systembartint.SystemBarTintManager;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@InjectView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;
@InjectView(R.id.tabs)
PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
@InjectView(R.id.pager)
ViewPager pager;

private MyPagerAdapter adapter;
private Drawable oldBackground = null;
private int currentColor;
private SystemBarTintManager mTintManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // create our manager instance after the content view is set
    mTintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
    // enable status bar tint
    mTintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics());
    pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);
    pager.setCurrentItem(1);
    changeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

    tabs.setOnTabReselectedListener(new PagerSlidingTabStrip.OnTabReselectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab reselected: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_contact:
            QuickContactFragment.newInstance().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "QuickContactFragment");
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void changeColor(int newColor) {
    tabs.setBackgroundColor(newColor);
    mTintManager.setTintColor(newColor);
    // change ActionBar color just if an ActionBar is available
    Drawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(newColor);
    Drawable bottomDrawable = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{colorDrawable, bottomDrawable});
    if (oldBackground == null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(ld);
    } else {
        TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]{oldBackground, ld});
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(td);
        td.startTransition(200);
    }

    oldBackground = ld;
    currentColor = newColor;
}

public void onColorClicked(View v) {
    int color = Color.parseColor(v.getTag().toString());
    changeColor(color);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("currentColor", currentColor);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    currentColor = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentColor");
    changeColor(currentColor);
}

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] TITLES = {"Categories", "Home", "Top Paid", "Top Free", "Top Grossing", "Top New Paid",
            "Top New Free", "Trending"};

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}
```

}

and the second code of the textview where i want to change it to webview.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;

public class SuperAwesomeCardFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

@InjectView(R.id.textView)
TextView textView;

private int position;

public static SuperAwesomeCardFragment newInstance(int position) {
    SuperAwesomeCardFragment f = new SuperAwesomeCardFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card,container,false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);
    ViewCompat.setElevation(rootView,50);
    textView.setText("CARD "+position);
    return rootView;
}
```

}

that's all for now, the layouts files are less important, i will deal with it later.

Answer (score 0):

You should `setOnPageChangeListener` and use `webview.loadUrl(url1);`

```
tabsStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
                webview.loadUrl(url1);
                break;
            case 1:
                webview.loadUrl(url2);
                break;
            case 2:
                webview.loadUrl(url3);
                break;                  
            }
    }

    // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        // Code goes here
    }

    // Called when the scroll state changes: 
    // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        // Code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, it worked like you said, the tabs are changing the sites now but the sites dosent load. it shows "webpage not 
avalible", i already added the internet permission on manifest

Comment: nevermind,somehow i fixed it, but if you have any suggestion on how to make it better to work i will be glad to listen. thanks you very much armistize.